# Sticky arrival, non-sticky departure (w/o JS)

Tags: html, css

Decided to give `position: sticky` a go since support has improved. Below is a demo that I created.

```css
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0}
main{width:57.5vh;height:375vh;position:absolute;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);font-family:arial black;color:#fff;background:gold}

.title{--height:25vh;height:var(--height);position:sticky;text-align:center;line-height:var(--height)}
.e{background:pink}
.o{background:skyblue}

main>div:nth-child(1){height:100vh}
main>div:nth-child(2){z-index:5;top:0} /* STEP: 1 */
main>div:nth-child(3){height:75vh}

main>div:nth-child(4){height:150vh;position:sticky;top:25%;border:solid red 2px;box-sizing:border-box}

main>div:nth-child(4)>div:nth-child(1){z-index:3;top:25%} /* STEP: 2 */
main>div:nth-child(4)>div:nth-child(2){height:50vh}
main>div:nth-child(4)>div:nth-child(3){z-index:2;top:50%} /* STEP: 3 */
main>div:nth-child(4)>div:nth-child(4){height:25vh}
main>div:nth-child(4)>div:nth-child(5){z-index:1;top:75%} /* STEP: 4 */

.gap{height:100vh;background:limegreen}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div class='title e'>STEP: 1</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div class='title o'>STEP: 2</div>
    <div></div>
    <div class='title e'>STEP: 3</div>
    <div></div>
    <div class='title o'>STEP: 4</div>
    <div class='gap'>GAP</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Is it possible to push 'STEP 2', 'STEP 3', and 'STEP 4' cards off of the screen at the same time instead of the bottom of the container pushing them off the screen one by one? I know the current "one-by-one" behavior is normal, but is there a hacky way or, better yet, a non-hacky way around this normal behavior?

I have tried using `bottom` instead of `top`, a few other things, and even sticking the three cards in a container because I am desperate for a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it, if you push all steps outside of the screen when you scroll up, what happens when you scroll down again if you're at the top?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy the exact inverse. if u scroll back up, they come back down as a "block" as if "GAP" is pulling them until the point they stopped being sticky, at which point they act in reverse to their initial sticky behavior

Comment: Yea well I've got no idea how to do that so here's a +1 for the road. Here's a hint I found tho https://css-tricks.com/styling-based-on-scroll-position/

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy haha thanks for the upvote <3 to be honest, i am not even sure it is possible without JS. i have been mulling over the idea for hours now without any new ideas whatsoever...

Comment: maybe you need try it out on jQuery

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa i want to see if it is possible to do without JS (as the title states)